# JavaScript findMax() example - Need an Explanation

Tags: javascript, function

I'm going through a W3Schools tutorial on JavaScript and I was just wondering about this findMax() function:

```
function findMax() {
    var i;
    var max = -Infinity;
    for (i = 0, i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] > max) {
            max = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I understand that 'i' is a counter, the function goes until everything has been counted, and the count is increased by 1.  What I don't understand - how does creating an if statement (arguments[i] > max) ... get the highest number in the findMax() function?  Why does passing i into the if statement give the max number back?

Comment: Well for each argument `argument[i]` you need to see if it's greater than the previously-known max `max`.

Comment: The loop iterates over the arguments passed into the function, and `arguments[i]` is the current argument. If it's more than what's currently stored in `max`, update `max` with that number, and so when the loop completes, `max` is the highest number iterated over.

Comment: Consider printing out the values of `max` and the `arguments[i]` after every iteration of the `for` loop, and you'll see why it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that particular line of code, the loop is checking each value with the arguments array to see if it higher than the currently highest value saved in `max`.  If it is not, then it moves on to the next one.  If it is, then it changes `max` to the new highest value.  Once the loop has checked each value in the `arguments` array, then the function returns the highest value (`max`).

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement doesn't look directly at the value of i. Instead, it is used as an index to a specific value in the array `arguments`.
Each time you find a value higher than all values you already saw, it means this is the new maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be thinking that `max` is being compared to `i`. That's not the case. `i` is being used to loop through the elements of `arguments`.

Lets say that you call `findMax` like this `findMax(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. Then `arguments` is equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

What happens then is that your for loop will iterate through each of the elements of `arguments`.

- `if (arguments[0] > max)` is the same as Is 1 > -Infinity? (yes)
- `if (arguments[1] > max)` is the same as Is 2 > 1? (yes)
- `if (arguments[2] > max)` is the same as Is 3 > 2? (yes)
- `if (arguments[3] > max)` is the same as Is 4 > 3? (yes)
- `if (arguments[4] > max)` is the same as Is 5 > 4? (yes)

Which gives you 5 as the max.